# I need action bar tabs with custom title bar android

Tags: android

I need action bar tabs with custom title bar in android. I am using this code

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.customtitle);
```

but it isn't working properly. Currently tabs are showing below title. I need title to show below tabs. Can anyone help me?

Comment: are you using xml to create menu?

Comment: could you publish screenshots of what you are trying to do and what you obtain ?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html

```
setCustomView(View view, ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams)
```

this function take ActionBar.LayoutParams parameter in second parameter.
So you can do it

```
final View actionCustomView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(actionCustomView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: This is not centralised.I need centralised title